# If you dont have %f in C, how to write a C program to print decimal number upto 2 decimal places without %f?

Tags: c

Please Help me in writing a C program for my question.

Ques- You dont have `%f` in C. how to write a C program to print decimal number upto 2 decimal places without using `%f`?

Comment: Use `%d.%d` and print the integer part and the fractional part.

Comment: Or you could use `%g` ?

Comment: You want to print float data without using %f or any other interger data ?

Comment: Fortunately, C does come with the %f format specifier, so your question doesn't make any sense. Ask your teacher about such nonsense instead, as this is no doubt your assignment/homework question.

Comment: @Lundin, I believe he is aware of the existence of %f, and this is a constraint forced upon him, probably in his HW

Comment: @Lundin I think his teacher wanted them to think some smart, ad-hoc way of printing decimals from scratch, without recursing to the (available) %f (see answer by Alter Mann below, for example).

Comment: @HadarGrubman Nonsense, there is no hw that would prevent the use of %f. If you have no FPU and your compiler is so bad and non-compliant that it didn't implement floating point through software, you wouldn't be able to use floats in the first place.

Comment: @Lundin, Many times during my programming education the professors forced me not to use some straight forward method, so I could do stuff 
"The Hard Way" and learn some new things

Comment: @HadarGrubman No doubt, but this is a programming site, where artificial problems with no connection to the real world are too localized. Answering such questions isn't helping anyone but the OP.

Comment: @Lundin, I agree with you...

Comment: So is HW "hardware" or "homework"? Or either?

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double num = 3.1416, a, b;

    b = modf(num, &a) * 10000;
    printf("%d.%d\n", (int)a, (int)b);
    return 0;
}
```

As pointed out by @mch it doesn't works for numbers like 3.04, a solution that works ([provided by Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25260127/1606345)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void dbl2str(char *s, double number, int decimals)
{
    double integral, fractional, epsilon = 1e-9;
    double round = 0.5 * pow(10, -decimals);
    int n, i;

    fractional = modf(number + round + epsilon, &integral);
    n = sprintf(s, "%d%c", (int)integral, decimals ? '.' : 0);
    for (i = 0; i < decimals; i++) {
        fractional *= 10;
        s[n + i] = '0' + (int)fractional;
        fractional = modf(fractional, &integral);
    }
    s[n + i] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[32];

    dbl2str(s, 3.1416, 4);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    dbl2str(s, 3.159, 4);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    dbl2str(s, 3.05, 3);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3.1416
3.1590
3.050
```

Comment: The only downside is the requirement to know the number of significant decimal places in `num`.

Comment: Why did you multiplied the modf by 10000?

Comment: it would work with `%02d` or in your example with `%05d`, but your method is more all-round

Comment: but the question asked for only two, you simply overkilled it

Comment: the rounding error is because `3.1416` in double precision is `3.141599999999999948130380289512686431407928466796875` and so a `5` is the 4th digit. at the last digit you can look after the next digit and round up if it is > 4.

Answer (score 2):

**Why we need any hack ? Lets go by standard**

If your float data is **Single-precision floating-point format**

Then i would go with format specification.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Here in 32 bit float

```
Sign bit: 1 bit
Exponent width: 8 bits
Significand precision: 24 bits (23 explicitly stored)
```

SO you can decode this things and print using `%d.%02d` to show integral and 2 decimals

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
float f = 23.48987;
int integerPart = (int)f; // integerPart = 23
int decimalPart = (int)(f*100 - integerPart*100); // decimalPart = 48
printf("%d.%02d", integerPart, decimalPart); // printed value - 23.48
```