# Round error converting from double to string without using %f

Tags: c, floating-point

Following this question:

[If you dont have %f in C, how to write a C program to print decimal number upto 2 decimal places without %f?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25257320/1606345)

This is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void dbl2str(char *s, double number, int decimals)
{
    double integral, fractional;
    int n, i;

    fractional = modf(number, &integral);
    n = sprintf(s, "%d%c", (int)integral, decimals ? '.' : 0);
    for (i = 0; i < decimals; i++) {
        fractional *= 10;
        s[n + i] = '0' + (int)fractional;
        fractional = modf(fractional, &integral);
    }
    s[n + i] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[32];

    dbl2str(s, 3.1416, 4);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    dbl2str(s, 3.159, 4);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    dbl2str(s, 3.04, 2);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3.1415
3.1589
3.04
```

As you can see there are round errors, is there a way to get the correct output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like

```
void dbl2str(char *s, double number, int decimals)
{
    double integral, fractional;
    int n, i;

    /* use an epsilon and add the correct rounding value */
    double eps= 1e-9;
    double round = 0.5*pow(10,-decimals);

    fractional = modf(number+round+eps, &integral);
    n = sprintf(s, "%d%c", (int)integral, decimals ? '.' : 0);
    for (i = 0; i < decimals; i++) {
        fractional *= 10;
        s[n + i] = '0' + (int)fractional;
        fractional = modf(fractional, &integral);
    }
    s[n + i] = '\0';
}
```

This way, I add 0.5*10^-decimals to get the `(int) fractional` to round correctly up to an epsilon.

It works for your input:

```
3.1416
3.1590
3.04
```

Of course, you may need to adjust the epsilon, depending on the digits, and then think about the case where you have exhausted your 16 digit precision. Overall, this is very hard to do right.

Comment: Try printing out `1e100` with this method.  `(int)integral` elicits undefined behaviour because `integral` is too big to be represented by an `int`.  The "two decimal places" part is the easy part of this question; handling really big numbers would seem to require either something very intelligent or arbitrary-precision arithmetic.

Comment: @tmyklebu Yes, there are multiple ways where this can and will go wrong. I would never rely on it. As a bonus, it fails for negative values, too. As I said, it works for the input and values around those presented. It will surely fail for values less then 1e-9 and for some input with more significant digits then 10 after the decimal point (because of the epsilon used). But in these cases, you have other numerical issues (as with 1e100).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 0.0006 isn't exactly representable in binary instead the representation will exactly match something like 0.0005999... This means that when you do the multiplication by 10 four times you get 5 as your last digit instead of 10. You need to look at the next digit in your sequence and round appropriately (the next digit will be greater than 5 in this case).

Be careful with the rounding because rounding up the last digit may cause the one before to round up as well (if the last digit was also a 9).

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
s[n + i] = '0' + (int)fractional;
```

*truncates* the `fractional` part to an integer. You want the last digit to be correctly *rounded*, so you have to treat it different than the others:

```
void dbl2str(char *s, double number, int decimals)
{
    double integral, fractional;
    int n, i;

    fractional = modf(number, &integral);
    if (fractional < 0)
        fractional = -fractional;
    n = sprintf(s, "%d%c", (int)integral, decimals ? '.' : 0);
    for (i = 0; i < decimals-1; i++) {
        fractional *= 10;
        s[n++] = '0' + (int)fractional;
        fractional = modf(fractional, &integral);
    }
    fractional *= 10;
    s[n++] = '0' + (int)(fractional+0.5f);
    fractional = modf(fractional, &integral);
    s[n] = '\0';
}
```

I added a test for negative numbers as well. Without, the `fractional` part goes wild.

Comment: Thank you @Jongware, also fails for `dbl2str(s, 3.159, 4);`

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
 if(i == decimals - 1)
                fractional = round(fractional);
```

after  `fractional *= 10;`

Comment: Thank you Igor, this was my first attempt, but fails for  `dbl2str(s, 3.159, 4);`

Comment: @AlterMann why `dbl2str(s, 3.159, 4);` instead of `dbl2str(s, 3.159, 3);` ? Is an implementation needed even for the case when the number of decimal characters is wrong? If that is the case should it print 0's or nothing?